# I need to check if a date already exists in Excel file using pyexcel or openpyx

Tags: excel, python-3.x

Right now this script is not recognizing when dates in the excel file match the date I am looking for (today's date). I am new to programming, so if you can could you please explain the changes you have made in a simple way that would really help me.
This is the picture of how this code currently edits Excel. https://prnt.sc/pse0xt  As you can see there are duplicates of dates and I want to have every date entered only ONCE.

Here is what I am trying:

```
import datetime
import openpyxl
import pyexcel

date = (datetime.date.today())
date_already_exists = False

# File to open PyExcel
file_name = "example.xlsx"
sheet = pyexcel.get_sheet(file_name = file_name)

# File to open OpenPyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_name, read_only=True)
ws = wb.active

# Decides whether to write a new entry
for row in ws.rows:
    if row[1].value == date:
        date_already_exists = True

if date_already_exists is False:
   sheet.row += [date, "X"]

# Saves the file
sheet.save_as(array = sheet.row, filename = file_name)
```

Comment: Hunch: Your issue is comparing a datetime object to an excel value. How is the date formatted in excel? Figure that out, and then format your datetime to match so you can do a comparison like you're doing now. Assuming your excel date is `11/1/2019', you would do `date = datetime.date.today().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')`

Comment: Yes, in order to see for sure we would need to see the excel data. Also, the alternative would be to convert the excel data to a pd.datetime, but Jtcrithers answer is better because you only have to convert one thing. However, if the excel dates are variably formatted then it may be better to convert the excel dates to datetimes.

Comment: Added a picture of Excel.